# Are functions objects or types in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In his *Eloquent Javascript*, Haverbeke claims that (page 16):

*"In a JavaScript system, most of this data is neatly separated into things called           values. Every value has a type, which determines the kind of role it can play. There are six basic types of values: numbers, strings, Booleans, objects, functions, and undefined values."*

But Crockford in *Javascript: The Good Parts* says:

*"The simple types of JavaScript are numbers, strings, booleans (true and false), null, and undefined. All other values are objects. Numbers, strings, and booleans are object-like in that they have methods, but they are immutable. Objects in JavaScript are mutable keyed collections. In JavaScript, arrays are objects, functions are objects, regular expressions are objects, and, of course, objects are objects."*

Now, at least under V8 I get this:

```
> typeof function(){};
'function'
> typeof {};
'object'
```

I don't understand if object is a type and function is an object or if function and object are both types. I guess I'm missing the distinction between primitive types and other kind of types (composite types?).

Comment: Everything in JS is an Object. It is just like saying a square is a rectangle, but a rectangle is not a square.

Comment: @Derek: Not quite everything. JS has primitives *(non objects)*, and some of them have an object "wrapper", but not all.

Comment: It' easiest to just think of a function as a special type of object, much like an array is a special type of object.  They have the capabilities of an object, but also other capabilities that make them a different type of object.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They're a type of object.

The `typeof` is `"function"`:

```
typeof (function() {}) === "function" // true
```

The internal `[[Class]]` is `[object Function]`:

```
({}).toString.call(function() {}) === "[object Function]" // true
```

They're an instance of the `Function` constructor prototype:

```
(function(){}) instanceof Function // true
```

They're an instance of the `Object` constructor prototype:

```
(function(){}) instanceof Object // true
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to be careful when talking about types in javascript. Values have a [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8), which may be one of the following:

1. Undefined
2. Null
3. Boolean
4. String
5. Number
6. Object

Perversely, the value returned by the [`typeof` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) is not the Type, it's a string that is the same as the Type for most values, but is different for:

1. Null returns 'object', even though its Type is Null
2. An object that implements `[[Call]]` returns function, even though its Type is Object
3. Host objects can return anything they like other than one of the restricted values

So the bottom line is that the Type of a function is Object, but `typeof someFn` returns `function`.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript supports functional programming.  As a result all JavaScript functions are first-class functions, meaning that functions are treated like ordinary objects.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_functions

Comment: If they're treated completely like ordinary objects (e.g., `{}`) then why is `typeof {} !== typeof function() {}`?

Comment: @icktoofay—because ECMA-262 defines what the [`typeof` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) returns, and for some objects it doesn't return the Type (e.g. Null is the Null Type but `typeof Null` returns 'object').

Comment: (I was actually trying to get them to add that into the answer — It wasn't really something I was wondering about.)