# What does mutable keyed collection mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am reading the book JavaScript: The Good Parts. It is said that

> Objects in JavaScript are mutable keyed collections.

What does *mutable keyed collection* mean?

AS far as I could find on internet, mutable means the vales can be changes. I couldn't find what *keyed collection* mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are functions objects or types in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15399937/are-functions-objects-or-types-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are a collection of keys with associated values. This could be referred to as a "keyed collection":

```
var o = {
  foo: "bar",
  bar: "baz"
}
```

(Where `foo` and `bar` here are keys).

...which can be changed (as you've already said, the "mutable" part):

```
o.foo = "foobar";
o.foobar = "bar";
```

Comment: Is a _method's_ name also a _key_?

Comment: It can be, yes. If we define `o.foo = function() { ... }`, "foo" here is the key.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, Can you explain _All types except objects define immutable values (values, which are incapable of being changed)_ [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Primitive_values).. If possible..

Comment: @RayonDabre I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Doc says anything except `Object` are immutable(can not be changed) bit we do can change the values of `String`/`Number`..

Comment: @RayonDabre I guess it means other than _object_ every other **type** like Boolean, string, null, number etc are immutable.

Comment: @RayonDabre the documentation you've linked to already answers that question: "Unlike in languages like C, JavaScript strings are immutable. This means that once a string is created, it is not possible to modify it. However, it is still possible to create another string based on an operation on the original string.".

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, How it is not possible to modify it.. We do modify it.. This line itself is not clear!

Comment: @RayonDabre you can declare `var s = "hello, world"`. You can change `s` to anything you want, but you can't change `"hello, world"` itself to something other than `"hello, world"`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, Am still confused.. _you can't change "hello, world" ;(_ Any pointer will be appreciated! Thank a lot mate!

Comment: `"hello, world"` is the string `"hello, world"`, just like the number `5` is the number `5`. JavaScript doesn't let you change these. You can't change the number `5` to the number `12`. You *can* change the value of a variable to something different, but the actual value itself will always be that value. If we have `var x = 5;`, `x` is `5` and `5` is `5`. If we then change it to `x = 12;`, `x` is now `12`, but `5` is still `5`.

Comment: How can we relate this with `Object`(_anything except Object are immutable_) ?

Comment: @RayonDabre `var x` in this case would be part of the `window` object (in HTML). The number `5` isn't part of any object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109425/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-james-donnelly).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I got your point! Value of x can be changed! Hence object could be changed! but 5 can not be.. Immutable....Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The `keyed` keyword here means that the data is "named", "indexed" or "keyed".

```
{ 
 key : value,
 key2: value2 
}
```

a collection because it contains a collection of data.

Answer (score 0):

It is about the way objects work in Javascript, they behave like C# Dictionaries, for example, or named arrays in PHP. `obj.someKey` is equivalent to `obj['someKey']` and you can always change the values associated with those keys or indeed delete them.

More advanced: the key uniquely identifies the value stored with it and the system is optimized for performance, so you can use this to index information or to get distinct values of a list,etc.